Terminated gulp watch
I am using jquery and express (maybe) project.
This project node version is 12
If I run
gulp watch

Then It work.
But after I change my script file because of editing code,
[10:47:42] Finished 'js' after 984 ms
[10:47:42] Starting 'js'...
[Browsersync] 21 files changed (artist-calendar.min.js, artist-register.min.js, client-list.min.js, contact-register-confirm.min.js, contact-register.min.js, editable.min.js, globals.min.js, invoice.min.js, login.min.js, popup-artist-confirm.min.js, popup-artist-modify.min.js, profile.min.js, staff-calendar.min.js, staff-schedule-register.min.js, studio-calendar.min.js, studio-register-confirm.min.js, studio-schedule-register.min.js, user-list-table.min.js, user-modify.min.js, user-register.min.js, utils.min.js)

Above message keep showing.
After about 2 hours, frontend is shutdown and show below error
<--- Last few GCs --->
5)[15816:000001E38D34A920]  2103240 ms: Mark-sweep 2041.6 (2059.4) -> 2038.3 (2060.9) MB, 295.0 / 1.7 ms  (+ 493.2 ms in 104 steps since start of marking, biggest step 15.6 ms, walltime since start of marking 81 1: 00007FF670833B5F napi_wrap+119263
 2: 00007FF6707DA4A6 v8::internal::OrderedHashTable<v8::internal::OrderedHashSet,1>::NextTableOffset+38102
 3: 00007FF6707DB2A6 node::OnFatalError+438
 4: 00007FF671019C1E v8::Isolate::ReportExternalAllocationLimitReached+94
 5: 00007FF671001DD1 v8::SharedArrayBuffer::Externalize+833
 6: 00007FF670EB358C v8::internal::Heap::EphemeronKeyWriteBarrierFromCode+1436
 7: 00007FF670EBE7D0 v8::internal::Heap::ProtectUnprotectedMemoryChunks+1312
 8: 00007FF670EBB2E4 v8::internal::Heap::PageFlagsAreConsistent+3204
 9: 00007FF670EB0AE3 v8::internal::Heap::CollectGarbage+1283
10: 00007FF670EAF154 v8::internal::Heap::AddRetainedMap+2500
11: 00007FF670ED049D v8::internal::Factory::NewFillerObject+61
12: 00007FF670C33A91 v8::internal::interpreter::JumpTableTargetOffsets::iterator::operator=+1665
13: 00007FF67146F4BD v8::internal::SetupIsolateDelegate::SetupHeap+546925
14: 00007FF6714703ED v8::internal::SetupIsolateDelegate::SetupHeap+550813
15: 000000DDDA80A38E

Why it is happen and I can I solve?
My gulp file is below
"use strict";

// Load plugins
const autoprefixer = require("gulp-autoprefixer");
const browsersync = require("browser-sync").create();
const cleanCSS = require("gulp-clean-css");
const del = require("del");
const gulp = require("gulp");
const header = require("gulp-header");
const merge = require("merge-stream");
const plumber = require("gulp-plumber");
const rename = require("gulp-rename");
const sass = require("gulp-sass");
const uglify = require("gulp-uglify");
const http = require("http");

// Load package.json for banner
const pkg = require('./package.json');

// Set the banner content
const banner = ['/*!\n',
  ' * Start - <%= pkg.title %> v<%= pkg.version %> (<%= pkg.homepage %>)\n',
  ' * Copyright -' + (new Date()).getFullYear(), ' <%= pkg.author %>\n',
  ' * Licensed under <%= pkg.license %> (<%= pkg.name %>)\n',
  ' */\n',
  '\n'
].join('');

// BrowserSync
function browserSync(done) {
  browsersync.init({
    ghostMode: false,
    notify: false,
    open: false,
    server: {
      baseDir: "./",
      index: "login.html"
    },
    port: 8080
  });
  done();
}

// BrowserSync reload
function browserSyncReload(done) {
  browsersync.reload();
  done();
}

// Clean vendor
function clean() {
  return del(["./vendor/"]);
}

// Bring third party dependencies from node_modules into vendor directory
function modules() {
  // Bootstrap JS
  var bootstrapJS = gulp.src('./node_modules/bootstrap/dist/js/*')
    .pipe(gulp.dest('./vendor/bootstrap/js'));
  // Bootstrap SCSS
  var bootstrapSCSS = gulp.src('./node_modules/bootstrap/scss/**/*')
    .pipe(gulp.dest('./vendor/bootstrap/scss'));
  // ChartJS
  var chartJS = gulp.src('./node_modules/chart.js/dist/*.js')
    .pipe(gulp.dest('./vendor/chart.js'));
  // dataTables
  var dataTables = gulp.src([
      './node_modules/datatables.net/js/*.js',
      './node_modules/datatables.net-bs4/js/*.js',
      './node_modules/datatables.net-bs4/css/*.css'
    ])
    .pipe(gulp.dest('./vendor/datatables'));
  // Font Awesome
  var fontAwesome = gulp.src('./node_modules/@fortawesome/**/*')
    .pipe(gulp.dest('./vendor'));
  // jQuery Easing
  var jqueryEasing = gulp.src('./node_modules/jquery.easing/*.js')
    .pipe(gulp.dest('./vendor/jquery-easing'));
  // jQuery
  var jquery = gulp.src([
      './node_modules/jquery/dist/*',
      '!./node_modules/jquery/dist/core.js'
    ])
    .pipe(gulp.dest('./vendor/jquery'));
  return merge(bootstrapJS, bootstrapSCSS, chartJS, dataTables, fontAwesome, jquery, jqueryEasing);
}

// CSS task
function css() {
  return gulp
    .src("./scss/**/*.scss")
    .pipe(plumber())
    .pipe(sass({
      outputStyle: "expanded",
      includePaths: "./node_modules",
    }))
    .on("error", sass.logError)
    .pipe(autoprefixer({
      browsers: ['last 2 versions'],
      cascade: false
    }))
    .pipe(header(banner, {
      pkg: pkg
    }))
    .pipe(gulp.dest("./css"))
    .pipe(rename({
      suffix: ".min"
    }))
    .pipe(cleanCSS())
    .pipe(gulp.dest("./css"))
    .pipe(browsersync.stream());
}

// JS task
function js() {
  return gulp
    .src([
      './js/*.js',
      '!./js/*.min.js',
    ])
    .pipe(uglify())
    .pipe(header(banner, {
      pkg: pkg
    }))
    .pipe(rename({
      suffix: '.min'
    }))
    .pipe(gulp.dest('./js'))
    .pipe(browsersync.stream());
}

// Watch files
function watchFiles() {
  gulp.watch("./scss/**/*", css);
  gulp.watch("./js/**/*", js);
  gulp.watch("./**/*.html", browserSyncReload);
}

// Define complex tasks
const vendor = gulp.series(clean, modules);
const build = gulp.series(vendor, gulp.parallel(css, js));
const watch = gulp.series(build, gulp.parallel(watchFiles, browserSync));

// Export tasks
exports.css = css;
exports.js = js;
exports.clean = clean;
exports.vendor = vendor;
exports.build = build;
exports.watch = watch;
exports.default = build;


